# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined in Visual
>   Studio Enterprise 2015

There is any alternative to fix this issue without adding the crystalreportviewers13 Folder in Project. I am Facing Ajax control not working properly(Like Calendar control)  and data grid link button not working. Please suggest me if any other solution.

Thanks & Best Regards,
Raj Kumar

Comment: Have you tried to browse your page with another browser?

Answer (score 0):

One thing we did was to add that folder to IIS, under:
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\YOUR DOT NET VERSION